# Clojure nested doseq loop

Tags: loops, clojure, nested

I'm new to Clojure and I have a question regarding nested doseq loops.

I would like to iterate through a sequence and get a subsequence, and then get some keys to apply a function over all the sequence elements.

The given sequence has an structure more or less like this, but with hundreds of books, shelves and many libraries:

```
([:state/libraries {6 #:library {:name "MUNICIPAL LIBRARY OF X" :id 6 
:shelves {3 #:shelf {:name "GREEN SHELF" :id 3 :books  
{45 #:book {:id 45 :name "NECRONOMICON" :pages {...}, 
{89 #:book {:id 89 :name "HOLY BIBLE" :pages {...}}}}}}}}])
```

Here is my code:

```
(defn my-function []   (let [conn  (d/connect (-> my-system :config :datomic-uri))]
(doseq [library-seq (read-string (slurp "given-sequence.edn"))]
  (doseq [shelves-seq (val library-seq)]
    (library/create-shelf conn {:id (:shelf/id (val shelves-seq)) 
                                :name (:shelf/name (val shelves-seq))})
    (doseq [books-seq (:shelf/books (val shelves-seq))]
      (library/create-book conn (:shelf/id (val shelves-seq)) {:id (:book/id (val books-seq))
                                                               :name (:book/name (val books-seq))})
                                                               )))))
```

The thing is that I want to get rid of that nested doseq mess but I don't know what would be the best approach, since in each iteration keys change. Using recur? reduce?  Maybe I am thinking about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: `library/create-*` functions act entirely through side effects? They don't return anything?

Comment: If that is the case, nested doseqs are probably the neatest here. Note that for the first 2 doseqs at least, you can compress them down to `(doseq [library-seq ..., shelves-seq ...] ...)`. You don't need a new `doseq` for every sequence. They can be grouped like with `for`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Carcigenicate says in the comments, presuming that the library/... functions are only side effecting, you can just write this in a single `doseq`.

```
(defn my-function []
  (let [conn  (d/connect (-> my-system :config :datomic-uri))]
    (doseq [library-seq (read-string (slurp "given-sequence.edn"))
            shelves-seq (val library-seq)
            :let [_ (library/create-shelf conn
                                          {:id (:shelf/id (val shelves-seq))
                                           :name (:shelf/name (val shelves-seq))})]
            books-seq (:shelf/books (val shelves-seq))]
      (library/create-book conn
                           (:shelf/id (val shelves-seq))
                           {:id (:book/id (val books-seq))
                            :name (:book/name (val books-seq))}))))
```

I would separate "connecting to the db" from "slurping a file" from "writing to the db" though. Together with some destructuring I'd end up with something more like:

```
(defn write-to-the-db [conn given-sequence]
  (doseq [library-seq given-sequence
          shelves-seq (val library-seq)
          :let [{shelf-id   :shelf/id,
                 shelf-name :shelf/name
                 books      :shelf/books} (val shelves-seq)
                _ (library/create-shelf conn {:id shelf-id, :name shelf-name})]
          {book-id :book/id, book-name :book/name} books]
    (library/create-book conn shelf-id {:id book-id, :name book-name})))
```

Comment: Basically what I hash in my head. The `_ (library/create-shelf` part is unfortunate though. I'd almost give the third seq its own `doseq`  just so `let` isn't being used to carry out side effects.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that that's a bit gross. A `:do` would be nicer if it existed.